# Pydantic list of dictionaries converted to single dict with its keys

Tags: python, dictionary, pydantic

I have following pydantic base model:

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel

class WSMessage(BaseModel):
    action: str
    success: Optional[bool] = None
    sent_from: Optional[str] = None
    send_to: Optional[str] = None
    data: Optional[Union[str, Dict, List]] = None
    msg: Optional[Union[str, Dict, List]] = None
    reason: Optional[Union[str, Dict, List]] = None
    class Config:
        extra = "allow"
```

And the following data:

```py
data = {
    'action': 'reply',
    'sent_from': 'master',
    'send_to': '192.168.0.100_UE4yWw69iSBEf67JhhWTpg==',
    'data': None,
    'success': True,
    'msg': [
        {'name': 'entry1_name', 'value': 'entry1_value'},
        {'name': 'entry2_name', 'value': 'entry2_value'}
    ],
    'reason': None,
    'to_action': 'get_system_properties',
    'completed': True,
}
```

However when I try to load the values into pydantic model, `data['msg']` is translated to a single dict instead of list of dicts.

```py
>>> msg = WSMessage(**data)
>>> msg
WSMessage(
    action='reply',
    success=True,
    sent_from='jumphost',
    send_to='46.235.96.113_UE4yWw69iSBEf67JhhWTpg==',
    data=None,
    msg={'name': 'value'},
    reason=None,
    completed=True,
    to_action='get_system_properties'
)
>>> msg.msg
{'name': 'value'}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want `msg` to accept any form of data. Or more specifically, string, dict or list.

If I remove `'msg'` from my model, it will properly parse it to list of dict.

Answer (score 2):

Your code *almost* works. First, you should use `List[dict]` over `List` since it is more precise. Second, when you use a `Union` to define a field, pydantic will match in the order of the union (first matching data structure).

**As your code is written:**

```
msg: Optional[Union[str, Dict, List[Dict]] = None
```

Given a list of dictionaries, pydantic will try to coerce your value to a `dict` (before attempting a list of `dict`) – since the first object in your list is a dictionary, it can successfully coerce it and it completes.

**If you switch the order of the union:**

```
msg: Optional[Union[str, List[Dict], Dict]] = None
```

Pydantic will now first check if the value is a list of dictionaries, before resolving to match a dictionary. This should now work.

**Relevantly:** Discriminated unions are an oft debated subject in pydantic:

- https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/619
- https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4675

Comment: _"it's considered best practice to put config at the top of your model"_ Source, please? Aside from that, if you are already specifying generic types (which is in fact a good idea), you should do it consistently. `Dict` is generic too, so you should do `Dict[str, str]` (or whatever is applicable). Not just for aesthetic reasons (consistency), but also because it impacts data validation in Pydantic models.

Comment: 1) Scratched the comment about `config`, did some peeking around, looks like that's how curr documentation is written, but no specific strictness or recommendation for how to declare it. 2) I agree, specific >> generic. My intention in the response is to be consistent with the OP's code. (Maybe `Dict` is a placeholder for a more detailed object?)

Comment: "Given a list of dictionaries, pydantic will match Dict *since the first object in your list* is a dictionary." - Ew. Did nobody tell them, "explicit is better than implicit"? Why would I write `X` if I want to match `List[X]`? Therefore, if I write `X`, why should it match `List[X]`?

Comment: Changed the language here @KarlKnechtel ^ I'm not sure what your comment is suggesting.

Comment: I'm just commenting on the Pydantic API. From what you say about how it works, I don't like the design.

Comment: Gotya. I think your specific concern applies to non-annoted types. This goes a bit beyond my current understanding of the domain, but I encourage you to dig deeper. @KarlKnechtel